# How to get Grunt working..?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have read a lot of different posts before asking here but I can't get through that error "Uglify not found"..

I have downloaded node.js, uglfy.js.. Shortly I have followed all the steps here..
[How to install grunt and how to build script with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703598/how-to-install-grunt-and-how-to-built-script-with-it)

my Gruntjs file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: 'js/global.js',
                dest: 'js/build/global.min.js'
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

and package.json:

```
{
    "name": "contentImageSlider",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.3.3",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0"
    },
    "description": "slider",
    "main": "Gruntfile.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/haldunatar/contentImageSlider.git"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/haldunatar/contentImageSlider/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/haldunatar/contentImageSlider"
}
```

**Error :**

```
Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. is it installed?
Warning:Tast 'uglify' not found. use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

So every time as I enter "grunt", it gives that error..but I downloaded uglify.js..

Can anybody help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide your `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` files?  And can you provide the full output for the command that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the "grunt-contrib-uglify" is in your `package.json` file, but the error indicates it's not installed.  Perhaps you recently added the dependency but did not perform an `npm install`?  Try running `npm install` from the root directory, then re-running `grunt`.

Comment: holy, moly!!:) Thanx alot!

Comment: Sure no problem, glad it worked!  You may have downloaded the uglify code, but maybe it wasn't added in the correct location (within the `node_modules` directory).  By using `npm install` you'll be sure the dependencies are installed in the correct location.