# On Installing grunt, Unable to find Gruntfile. What to do?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

On installing grunt I am having this problem. Although I have tried some commands which are given on stackoverflow in this [How to install grunt and how to build script with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703598/how-to-install-grunt-and-how-to-built-script-with-it) but still checking again by `grunt` command. Same result is showing. What should I do ?[image]

Comment: Unable to understand that why people are so negative over here. If I got some problem then I asked this question only. What is wrong with this that people are making negative?

Answer (score 0):

Installing grunt went just fine! You are just missing a file named `Gruntfile` in that directory, which is the file that tells grunt what to do. [Here is an example.](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) See also the [Getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) guide that the error message links to, from the section [Preparing a new Grunt project](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#preparing-a-new-grunt-project) onwards.

Comment: I tried these commands for the grunt file: npm install grunt --save-dev and npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev but still grunt file is not showing.

Comment: That is normal. _You_ need to write the Gruntfile. Grunt is like a cook; you need to give it some recipes :)